# Is it possible to verify a Windows EXE (PE file format) checksum under Linux?

Tags: windows, executable, hashsum

Windows EXE files which are in the PE format have a header and it contains a checksum.

Is it possible to verify it under Linux?

Because I am looking for a Linux command I hope you understand that this is a Linux and not a Windows question (please don't close it).

Comment: Can you give us an example? What would you verify it against? Do you want to calculate the checksum of the file and compare that to something you can extract from the file's header? Will you have the checksum stored in another file or variable? Please [edit] your question and explain what you need more clearly.

Comment: @terdon a *checksum* usually verifies the data out belongs to. I think you're thinking of verifying a signature.

Comment: @MarcusMüller you can't verify a checksum without having something to verify it against, right? This might be in another file, or it might be a question of generating the checksum and comparing to what is in the header (but, in that case, was the checksum in the header generated taking the header itself into account?). I realize all this will be obvious to someone used to handling these things in the Windows world, but they would need to be explained here. I may still be missing the point entirely, of course, you're quite right that I don't really know the first thing about this.

Comment: @terdon the last digit of your library card number is a checksum, and what is verified is the whole library card number. In the case of PE32, there is a header field CheckSum, which is computed over the whole PE32 image. So, the question does state what gets verified: the whole PE32 image, because that is what the checksum in the header of a PE32 executable is specified to do. You're right, the knowledge of what gets verified needs to be inherent (which is true for every checksum)

Comment: OK, fair enough, thanks @MarcusMüller. It would still be helpful to include this in the question since people here can have the knowledge of what tools can extract specific bits from a binary file, but won't necessarily know what they need to look for in a Windows executable.

Comment: True; but I'll admit I think anyone will have to look this up when trying to figure this out, unless they are WINE developers with experience in these headers or something; if my memory serves me well, it's a slightly misconstructed derivative version of some standardized checksum algorithm, and nothing aside from the windows kernel loading drivers, boot-time loaded DLLs, and DLLs into critical services ever verifies it. Says [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format). According to that, .exe files might have that header, but it's never being verified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of tools to do this; one such is [pefile](https://github.com/erocarrera/pefile/), a Python library with a build-in PE checksum verification function:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pefile
import sys

pe = pefile.PE(sys.argv[1])
if pe.verify_checksum():
    print("PE checksum verified")
else:
    print("PE checksum invalid")
```

(error-handling left as an exercise for the reader).

Save this as `verifype`, run `chmod 755 verifype`, then run it as `./verifype /path/to/pe.exe` to check `pe.exe`’s checksum.